# Capturar errors e Exceptions do PHP

Tags: php, log, exceção

#### Cenário

Sei que posso configurar os logs para que os erros e exceções sejam gravados, isso é legal, porem as vezes é demasiadamente chato ficar lendo esses arquivos.

#### Pergunta

1. Como capturar os **erros** e **exceções** afim de poder manipulá-los em tempo de execução?
2. Qual o impacto que isso pode causar sobre a performance da minha aplicação?

#### Objetivo

Existe um sistema online que interage com a aplicação, captura os erros e os mostra em um site (http://bugsnag.com).
A ideia é fazer um implementação `in-house` semelhante.

> Não responder com indicações de outros sistemas semelhantes. a pergunta tem escopo na implementação de tal funcionalidade, e não no uso de um sistema de terceiros.

Comment: Você quer capturá-los para fazer o que com eles? Se for para depurar, muitas vezes é importante saber o que o servidor estava fazendo quando o erro aconteceu. Pessoalmente, acho **mais difícil** fazê-lo quando os logs são separados e eu tenho que manter os dois abertos ao mesmo tempo e ficar comparando timestamps (ex.: o `access.log` e o `error.log` do Apache). Independentemente disso, considero sua pergunta válida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode capturar suas exceções assim com [`set_exception_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-exception-handler.php):

```php
function exceptionHandler($e) {
    Notificador::logarExcecao($e);
    throw $e;
}
set_exception_handler('exceptionHandler');
```

Dessa forma, você poderá manipular qualquer exceção não capturada. Para manipular os erros, utilize [`set_error_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-error-handler.php), que funciona de forma similar. Se você precisar de um controle mais específico, pode colocar no construtor da exceção, algo assim:

```php
class LogException extends Exception {
    public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0) {
        parent::__construct($message, $code);
        Notificador::logarExcecao($this);
    }
}
```

As suas demais exceções apenas extenderão esta `LogException`.

No método `logarExcecao($e)` você pode definir o que irá fazer ao receber uma exceção. Lembrando que você não deve fazer ações neste método que sejam muito custosas computacionalmente, já que isso pode comprometer a usabilidade do seu sistema. Acessar um arquivo de texto escrever nele provavelmente será mais rápido que acessar um DB com `PDO`, por exemplo. Nesse caso, podes definir uma rotina, por exemplo, de a cada 30min, enviar um report por e-mail, via cron jobs.

---

<sup>Você disse que não queria, mas ainda assim, para soluções mais robustas de LOG, eu recomendo a biblioteca [monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), que pode ser inserida no projeto via Composer.</sup>

Comment: Sim Calebe, eu conheço o Monolog e acho super interessante, porem o foco da pergunta era mostrar como é a interface do PHP para logs de terceiros

Comment: Se você for olhar a [documentação do bugsnag](https://bugsnag.com/docs/notifiers/php#configuration), verá que ele utiliza os mesmos métodos que utilizei.