# Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?

Tags: php, desempenho, estilo-de-codificação

No PHP, podemos suprimir erros utilizando o "arroba" antes de determinadas expressões.

Isso pode ser visto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50166/qual-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-no-inicio-de-express%C3%B5es-em-php/50167#50167).

Já assisti alguns *hangouts* sobre PHP e o pessoal estava criticando a utilização do `@` no PHP, pela tese de que um erro deve ser tratado, e não escondido.

O problema é que algumas funções do PHP retornam as vezes "mensagens indesejadas", como no caso do `unlink()`, que, ao não encontrar o arquivo para deletar, emite um `E_WARNING`.

Nesse caso, eu sempre utilizo o `@`.

Por exemplo:

```
 if (@unlink($filename)) {
     echo "Arquivo deletado com sucesso";
 }
```

Pois com o `@` o erro será suprimido e apenas retornará `FALSE` caso haja alguma falha. E isso é explicado na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50167/4995) do [@rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray).

Eu tenho algumas perguntas a fazer a respeito dessa prática:

- Do ponto de vista do desenvolvimento, eu deveria utilizar um `@` arroba para casos como da função `unlink`, ou configurar a exibição de erros para ocultar `E_WARNING`, ou fazer um `file_exists()` (em relação ao uso de `unlink()`) antes de fazer `unlink()`?
- O arroba pode ser prejudicial para o desempenho de uma aplicação? Ou o desencorajamento quanto ao uso do `@` só existe por questões de boas práticas de programação?

Comment: Relacionado: [Capturar errors e Exceptions do PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2532/91)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Como qualquer coisa, você pode usar sem problemas desde que saiba o que está fazendo e que tenha um bom motivo para usar.

Em geral esta sintaxe não deve ser usada porque as pessoas não sabem todas consequências do seu uso, mas não usar pode levar as pessoas fazerem outras coisas piores, como é mostrado na pergunta.

## Race condition

Verificar se um arquivo existe antes de fazer uma operação com ele é pior, já que entre a verificação e a operação o arquivo pode deixar de existir, ou passar a existir. Isto é o que se chama de [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101), que é justamente a tentativa de fazer algo num momento em que o estado pode ter mudado.

Em vários casos o correto é deixar o erro ocorrer e verificar se ele ocorreu. Sempre existe um mecanismo que identifique isto, seja uma exceção tradicional, ou um código de erro - mesmo que seja apenas um `true` ou `false`. Então em casos assim o correto é usar esta informação.

## Críticas

Como o PHP tem realmente funções que além de gerar em código também emite uma informação para o interpretador, e isto pode ser apresentado para o usuário, aí o uso do `@` é adequado.

Talvez algumas das críticas colocadas sejam justamente por ter a obrigatoriedade de uso em algumas situações. Estas funções poderiam muito bem funcionar como funcionam sem a emissão de um *warning*. Outros criticam que algumas funções não fazem isto. Esse *warning* acaba sendo importante para o programador saber que ele precisa tratar. Então ele trata o erro e coloca o `@` para indicar que está ciente. Esta é a teoria. Na prática sabemos que os programadores colocam o `@` sem fazer tratamento adequado. A linguagem não pode fazer milagre.

Nenhuma linguagem pode se proteger de programador ruim. O PHP poderia ter um mecanismo melhor, ser mais consistente, mas sempre dá para programar errado.

## Desempenho e erros

Ele não causa erros diretos, mas é claro que indiretamente seu uso errado pode causar problemas porque algo esperado não está acontecendo. E erros indiretos são piores que os diretos, eles geram [efeitos colaterais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330341/101). E qualquer coisa que gere efeito colateral deve ser analisada com mais cuidado. Mas a maioria dos programadores sequer entendem o que é uma [expressão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168177/101), imagine saber o que é efeito colateral e outras coisas que deveriam ser básicas, mas são consideradas sofisticadas.

Não há ganho de desempenho em fazer isto. O custo do erro permanece o mesmo.

Há perda de desempenho pelo simples fato de usar a supressão de erros. Isto pode variar de versão para versão. Mas além do custo do erro ocorrer que já teria de qualquer forma, [há um *overhead* adicional](http://ideone.com/u6EBm2) ([teste realizado pelo Sean McArthur](http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance)) para tratar a supressão. O código intermediário gerado quando o `@` é usado fica maior, com instruções extras de custo nada desprezível em vários cenários. Além disto o PHP precisa acessar o INI e modificar temporariamente a exibição de erros e voltar ao estado original logo depois (parece que é ruim assim mesmo, mas podem ter melhorado isto).

É muito melhor evitar o erro. Não só porque é correto, mas também para evitar um duplo *overhead*.

## Boa prática

Toda boa prática é pensada - nem sempre cumpre isto - para evitar que erros e dificuldade de manutenção aconteçam. Boa prática é saber o que está fazendo e não seguir receitas prontas, fazer porque ouviu falar.

A regra básica é nunca usar onde não precisa, porque está escondendo que é erro de programação mesmo, e o certo é consertar o problema. E usar onde precisa só quando não tem outra solução, porque é a forma que o PHP arrumou para te avisar que exige um tratamento do erro. Nestes casos faz até algum sentido de considerar o que expliquei acima.

Podemos considerar ele como o [*checked exception*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10732/101) de pobre.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Só pra acresentar: Você me deu a ideia de que, ao invés do "arroba gambiarra", posso então usar algo sofisticado como `set_error_handler` e transformá-lo numa exceção. Daí posso fazer um `try/catch` no unlink, por exemplo.

Comment: Sim, pode fazer isto.

Comment: Gostei do exemplo do race condition, +1.

Comment: Ótima explicação (+1)

Answer (score 12):

Ocultar mensagens de erros/warnings cria problemas sutis e difíceis de detectar, sem contar que o uso da arroba é *inline*, então se precisar remover terá que ser feito instrução por instrução.

**Usar ou não arroba?**

No exemplo do `unlink()`, e **algumas outras poucas**, é legitimo porque a função não tem um comportamento padrão. Ora retorna algo, ora simplesmente lança uma saída de texto.

Nessa situação opta-se pelo uso responsável da arroba, ou, se possível, procure por uma biblioteca externa para realizar a tarefa.