# Banco de dados não mostra os dados inseridos pelo usuário

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, estou tentando fazer um sistema de notícias, porém o banco de dados não recebe os dados do php. Gostaria de saber como resolver isso.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Inserir Notícia</title>    
</head>

<body>
    <?php

        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $banco = "sistemanoticias";
        $conexao = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
        mysql_select_db($banco) or die (mysql_error());

    ?>

    <?php 

        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $campo = $_POST['campo'];

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO noticias(titulo, campo) VALUES('$titulo, $campo)"); 
        echo "Notícia inserida com sucesso";
    ?>

    <a href="inicio.html">Retornar para o Início</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `VALUES('$titulo, $campo)` problemas com aspas...

Comment: eu arrumei esse erro, porém ainda continua não enviando.

Comment: Já considerou o uso do ```PDO``` no lugar do ```mysql```? Os benefícios são enormes.

Comment: Utilize `mysqli_*` ou `PDO` invés de `mysql_*`, porque a mesma se encontra DEPRECATED.

Comment: Aparece algum erro na tela? Já tentou usar `error_reporting(1);` ?

Answer (score 3):

Os campos de texto deve estar entre aspas simples cada um, sempre adicione `mysql_error()` para pegar a mensagem de erro do banco.

```
$titulo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['titulo']);
$campo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['campo']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO noticias(titulo, campo) VALUES('$titulo', '$campo')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Leitura recomendada:

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[MySQLi vs PDO - qual o mais recomendado para usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8302/91)

[Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/91)