# Tentando fazer funcionar o login, mas não mostra erro mas também não entra

Tags: php, mysql, login

Tipo fiz o php certo como o meu professor passou, mudei todos os nomes e tá tudo certo, já conferi, porém quando mando fazer o login, ele não entra, só atualiza a página e não redireciona para a página do perfil da pessoa como é para ser feito.

O código é esse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<?php
include ('config.php');
session_start();

if ($_POST['botao']=="Entrar"){

$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."' AND senha = '".$_POST['senha']."' ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or print mysql_error();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){

    while ($coluna=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $_SESSION["id_usuario"]= $coluna["id"]; 
        $_SESSION["email"] = $coluna["email"]; 
        $_SESSION["senha"] = $coluna["senha"]; 
        $_SESSION["UsuarioNivel"] = $coluna["nivel"];

        if($coluna['nivel'] == "USER"){ 
            header("Location: perfil.php"); 
            exit; 
        } 

        elseif($coluna['nivel'] == "ADM"){ 
            header("Location: restrita.php"); 
            exit;
        } 

        else {
            echo "Nenhum nível selecionado!";   
        }
        // ----------------------------------------------
    }
} else {
    echo "Login ou Senha Incorreto";    
}

}

?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cadastro" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>

<body>
<table border="0" class="banner"><tr><td colspan="4" align="center"><img src="banner.jpg" height="250" width="900"/></td></tr></table>
<br>
<table border="0" align="center" width="910">
    <tr class="link">
        <td> <a href="principal.php"> Home </a> </td>
        <td> <a href="perfil.php"> Meu perfil </a> </td> 
        <td> <a href="login.php"> Entrar </a> </td> 
        <td> <a href="login_funcionario.php"> Área restrita </a> </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
<br /> <br />
<table border="0" align="center">
<tr> <td colspan=3 align=center class="titulo"> Login </td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="texto"> Email: </td> <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" class="input"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="texto"> Senha: </td> <td colspan="2"> <input type="password" name="senha" maxlength="20" class="input"></td></tr>
<tr> <td colspan=2 align=right> 
    <input type="submit" name=botao id="botao" value="Entrar" class="botao">
    <input type="submit" name=botao value="Esqueci a senha" class="botao2">
</td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan=2 align=center>
    <br />
    <font class="texto"> Não é cadastrado? </font>
    <br />
    <font class="link"> <a href="cadastro.php"> Cadastre-se aqui </a>           </font>
</td>
</tr>
```

[image: resultados]

[image: estrutura]

Comment: Seu professor recomendou usar `@`?, está enviando por post?

Comment: se tirar o @ ele dá noticia, mas não muda em muita coisa, continua não funcionando e sim, por post

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione o `form` de envio, vc precisa trata esse notice, geralmente um if com `isset()` e a verificação do valor já resolve. Relacionado:[Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/91)

Comment: Jogue a linha `<form ...` para baixo da tag `<body>` lembre de fechar a tag `form` no final.

Comment: o session_start(); deve ser a primeira coisa do seu ficheiro php. tenha isso em atenção! Também não é boa política começar o form antes do head, alias, nunca tinha visto assim.

Comment: Outra nota, você está a comprar uma password encriptada com texto, isso vai dar sempre erro de autenticação. qual o método de encriptação usou para a password?

Answer (score 1):

Modifique o parâmetro `enctype` do teu formulário:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

É ele quem está causando o erro, pois com este parâmetro você está a dizer que está fazendo upload de um arquivo. Faça assim:

```
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

Comment: apaguei e continua dando a mesma coisa

Comment: Ao invés de apagar ponha da forma como eu editei na resposta. Assim funciona pra mim.

Comment: não deu certo do mesmo jeito

Comment: Oi, Diego, não precisa usar @nome-do-usuário dentro das perguntas/respostas. Isso só funciona nos comentários e o Autor da Pergunta é sempre notificado de novas respostas.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, eu faria um pouco diferente. Para que as condições sejam executadas e mostre um possível erro, mesmo que não seja de MySQL:

```
session_start();
if ($_POST['botao']=="Entrar"){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."' AND senha = '".$_POST['senha']."' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or print mysql_error();

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){

        while ($coluna=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $_SESSION["id_usuario"]= $coluna["id"]; 
            $_SESSION["email"] = $coluna["email"]; 
            $_SESSION["senha"] = $coluna["senha"]; 
            $_SESSION["UsuarioNivel"] = $coluna["nivel"];

            if($coluna['nivel'] == "USER"){ 
                header("Location: perfil.php"); 
                exit; 
            } elseif($coluna['nivel'] == "ADM"){ 
                header("Location: restrita.php"); 
                exit; 
            } else {
                echo "Nenhum nível selecionado!";   
            }
            // ----------------------------------------------
        }
    } else {
        echo "Login ou Senha Incorreto";    
    }

}
```

**Observação:**

O botão de envio deverá ter o name="botao" id="botao", para que o if() possa identificar. E o seu form deverá conter o method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"

No HTML você pode fazer:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
</style>

<body>
<table border="0" class="banner"><tr><td colspan="4" align="center"><img src="banner.jpg" height="250" width="900"/></td></tr></table>
<br>
<table border="0" align="center" width="910">
    <tr class="link">
        <td> <a href="principal.php"> Home </a> </td>
        <td> <a href="perfil.php"> Meu perfil </a> </td> 
        <td> <a href="login.php"> Entrar </a> </td> 
        <td> <a href="login_funcionario.php"> Área restrita </a> </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
<br /> <br />
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="cadastro" >
<table border="0" align="center">
<tr> <td colspan=3 align=center class="titulo"> Login </td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="texto"> Email: </td> <td colspan="2"> <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" class="input"> </td> </tr>
<tr> <td class="texto"> Senha: </td> <td colspan="2"> <input type="password" name="senha" maxlength="20" class="input"></td></tr>
<tr> <td colspan=2 align=right> 
    <input type="submit" name=botao id="botao" value="Entrar" class="botao">
    <input type="submit" name=botao value="Esqueci a senha" class="botao2">
</td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan=2 align=center>
    <br />
    <font class="texto"> Não é cadastrado? </font>
    <br />
    <font class="link"> <a href="cadastro.php"> Cadastre-se aqui </a>           </font>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: @AliniS e André, removi os comments aqui para a página não ficar poluída. Por favor juntem na pergunta e reposta informação que tenham trocado e seja relevante. Obrigado!