# erro em mysql_result()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou de novo buscando ajuda para entender um erro dado em uma chamada para mysql_result(), que não consigo resolver esse erro:

> Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object
>   given in C:\wamp\www\

eu não sei qual é o parâmetro que pede.

Esse é o código:

```
 <?php 
          $visitas_total = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT Sum(visitas) AS visitas FROM lp_post")
                        or die(mysql_error());
       if(@mysqli_num_rows($visitas_total) <= '0') echo '';
       $views = 0;
       $visitas = mysql_result($visitas_total, $views, 'Visitas') ;

         ?>
```

alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: por favor, arrume o post.

Comment: Desculpe querido pelo meu erro. Obrigado.

Comment: Tente tirar o terceiro parametro do `mysql_result` e diga qual foi o retorno

Comment: Desculpe Rafael Acioly, apaguei todos os comentários sem ter esse objetivo.Mas digo a você que na forma em me orientou, eliminou o erro, mas não printou para mim os números mas a palavra Array, pode me orientar como fazer?

Comment: tirando o terceiro 'visitas'  erro persiste

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` or `_array()` para obter o retorno da consulta, não misture a API mysql_ com a nova mysql**i**.

```
$sql = "SELECT Sum(visitas) AS visitas FROM lp_post";
$visitas_total = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));
if(mysqli_num_rows($visitas_total) <= 0){
    echo 'Nenhum resultado foi econtrado';
}else{
    $visitas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($visitas_total);
    echo $visitas['visitas']; 
}
```

Caso sua consulta retorne mais de uma linha, use um while para iterar todos os resultado.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($visitas_total)){
    echo $row['visitas'] .'<br>';
}
```

Leitura recomendada:

[Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/91)

Comment: @saulo vc precisa imprimir a chave certa do array, ela sempre vai ser o(s) nome(s) dos campos do banco de dados, então vai ser, `echo $visitas['visitas']`;

Comment: Muito obrigado a vos que com carinho pode ajudar-me, deu tudo certo. Obrigado.

Comment: @saulo, se a resposta resolveu o problema, pode marcar ela como aceita, [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91), também veja a [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor como o site funciona.