# Não consigo alterar registros de uma tabela do banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

É o seguinte, eu preciso fazer com que meu site possa alterar dados de login, registrados no banco de dados. Eu fiz os códigos, mas quando eu clico para alterar, nada acontece... Os arquivos que eu estou utilizando:

alteraadm.php

```
$conexao = @mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 

if (!$conexao)

die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());

$banco = mysql_select_db("vidal",$conexao); 

if (!$banco)
die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loginadm");

$i = 1;

$loop = 3;

while ($list = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    if ($i < $loop){

            echo
            '<tr align="justify" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 
            <td><a href="" >Usuario:'.$list['usuarioadm'].'</a><br></td>

            <form action="editar.php"><input type="submit" value="alterar" name="alterar"></form>  
            </tr>
        <tr>
            ';
    $i=0;
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
```

editar.php

```
<form method="post" action="update.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Codigo:<input type="text" name="codigologin" size="30"><br>
Usuario:<input type="text" name="usuarioadm" size="30"><br>
Senha:<input type="text" name="senhaadm" size="30"><br><br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="concluir" value="concluir" class="botao2">
 </form>
```

update.php

```
$conexao = @mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 

if (!$conexao)
die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());

$banco = mysql_select_db("vidal",$conexao); 

if (!$banco)
die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysql_error());

$codigologin= $_POST ["codigologin"];

$usuarioadm= $_POST["usuarioadm"];

$senhaadm= $_POST["senhaadm"];

$query = "UPDATE INTO `loginadm` ( `codigologin` , `usuarioadm` , `senhaadm`) VALUES ('$codigologin', '$usuarioadm', '$senhaadm')";

mysql_query($query,$conexao);

echo "Alteracao Realizada com sucesso!!!";

?>
```

Se alguém me ajudar a encontrar o erro, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro, não use as funções mysql_*, já foram removidas do php7, arrobas mais atrapalham do que ajudam elas ocultam os erros, uma mensagem de erro é melhor do 'nada acontecer'.

O problema é a sintaxe do seu update

```
$query = "UPDATE INTO `loginadm`
```

Se é um update deve ser como o código abaixo, **nunca esqueça** que a maioria dos updates tem um `WHERE` para especificar quais registros devem ser alterados, do contrario todas as linhas daquela tabela irão possuir os mesmos valores(em alguns casos isso pode ser proposital), backup, restaurações ou rollbacks serão necessários.

A sintaxe correta é:

```
UPDATE tabela SET 
   campo1 = valor1,
   campo2 = valor2,
   campo3 = valor3
WHERE id = valor_id
```

**Como identificar erros na consulta:**

Para conseguir identificar os erros de sintaxe e outros em operações com banco de dados, use a função que retorna o erro, nesse caso é o `mysql_error()` na execução da consulta que é feita por `mysql_query()`.

```
mysql_query($query,$conexao) or die(mysql_error());
```

Lembre de remover as arrobas e tratar os erros no lugar de ocultados.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/91)

[Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/91)

Comment: Consegui!! Muito obrigado.

Comment: @LuanWesley era só a sintaxe do update?