# Query não está sendo executada, não insere nada

Tags: php, mysql

O que pode estar errado? Não insere nada no banco.

Formulário:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="chk-gerente.php?nro_pergunta=<?php  echo $nro_pergunta; ?>" method="GET">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><b>Pergunta <?php echo"$ordem";?> de <?php echo"$totalpergunta";?></b></legend>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center><h3><label><?php echo"$descpergunta";?></label></h3></center>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="resp" id="optionsRadios1" value="5">OTIMO        </label></div>
                <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="resp" id="optionsRadios2" value="3">REGULAR      </label></div>
                <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="resp" id="optionsRadios3" value="1">RUIM         </label></div>
                <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="resp" id="optionsRadios4" value="0">NAO APLICADO </label></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $timestamp            = @mktime(date("H")-4, date("i"),date("s"),date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"),0);
        $DataCad              = gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp); // Gravar $DataCad no BD
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='loja'         id='loja'         value='$loja'>";
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='id_usuario'   id='id_usuario'   value='$id_usuario'>";
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='questionario' id='questionario' value='$questionario'>";
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='area'         id='area'         value='$area'>";
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='nro_pergunta' id='nro_pergunta' value='$nro_pergunta'>";     
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='DataCad'      id='DataCad'      value='$DataCad'>";
        echo"<input type='hidden' name='pergunta'     id='pergunta'     value='$idpergunta'>";
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                <button id='button' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Responder</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

O `INSERT` está no início da página:

```
require("conexao.php");

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $loja         = $_GET ["loja"];
    $id_ususario  = $_GET ["id_usuario"]; 
    $questionario = $_GET ["questionario"];
    $area         = $_GET ["area"];
    $idpergunta   = $_GET ["pergunta"];   
    $resp         = $_GET ["resp"]; 
    $datacad      = $_GET ["DataCad"]; 

    $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO respostas
        (resp_id,resp_loja,resp_usuario,resp_questionario,resp_area,resp_subgrupo,resp_pergunta_id,resp_resposta,resp_data,resp_status)
        VALUES
        ('','$loja','$id_usuario','$questionario','$area','1','$idpergunta','$resp','$DataCad','1')") 
        or die (mysql_error());
    @mysql_query($sql_insert,$conexao);
} else {
}
```

Tentei passar assim também e não foi...

```
include("conexao.php");
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $loja         = $_GET ["loja"];
    $id_ususario  = $_GET ["id_usuario"]; 
    $questionario = $_GET ["questionario"];
    $area         = $_GET ["area"];
    $idpergunta   = $_GET ["pergunta"];   
    $resp         = $_GET ["resp"]; 
    $datacad      = $_GET ["DataCad"]; 

    $sql=" INSERT INTO respostas
        (resp_id,resp_loja,resp_usuario,resp_questionario,resp_area,resp_subgrupo,resp_pergunta_id,resp_resposta,resp_data,resp_status)
        VALUES
        ('','$loja','$id_usuario','$questionario','$area','1','$idpergunta','$resp','$DataCad','1'";
} else {
}
```

Comment: Já tentou rodar o `Insert` direto no banco para ver se está funcionando?

Comment: Vale lembrar que as funções `mysql_*` já está depreciadas no PHP 5.5 (e removidas do 7.0)... migre para `MySQLi` ou `PDO_MySQL`

Comment: Deu certo sim direto pelo banco.

Comment: Remova todas as @ do código para ver a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Outra coisa: esse `@mysql_query($sql_insert,$conexao);` só estaria correto se `$sql_insert` fosse a query, mas é o resultado de uma query...

Comment: @Berriel ,olha lá por favor o que eu acrescentei ...

Comment: Faça o seguinte `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: do jeito que você fez não tem ação nenhuma, faça o que o @rray disse

Comment: Seria isso? ,porque a tela retornou vazia sem erro ... $sql = "INSERT INTO respostas 
  (resp_id,resp_loja,resp_usuario,resp_questionario,resp_area,resp_subgrupo,resp_pergunta_id,resp_resposta,resp_data,resp_status)
  VALUES 
  ('','$loja','$id_usuario','$questionario','$area','1','$idpergunta','$resp','$DataCad','1')" mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Isso, aparece algum erro?

Comment: Não,a tela fica em branco mesmo eu colocando o var_dump($sql); não mostra nada

Comment: coloca isso no inicio do arquivo, `ini_set('display_errors',true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Opa,começou a melhorar,fiz umteste aqui e se eu mudar: if(isset($_GET['submit'])){  para  if(getenv("REQUEST_METHOD") == "GET"){ ele da o insert,mais percebi se se atualizar a pagina insere,e o primeiro,insere vazio,to achando que a algo errado no GET,alguma dica?

Comment: aparece algum erro?

Comment: nesse ai não,insere normalmente

Comment: é que so de entrar na pagina já insere

Comment: @Otacio veja minha resposta para saber porque está inserindo só de entrar na página, e inserindo em branco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode mudar para

```
if (getenv("REQUEST_METHOD") == "GET") { ... }
```

Porque a requisição normal também é um GET. Nesse caso, ele vai inserir só de entrar na página, mas como o formulário ainda não foi enviado, os dados estarão em branco.

---

Tente isso:

```
include("conexao.php");
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $loja         = $_GET ["loja"];
    $id_ususario  = $_GET ["id_usuario"]; 
    $questionario = $_GET ["questionario"];
    $area         = $_GET ["area"];
    $idpergunta   = $_GET ["pergunta"];   
    $resp         = $_GET ["resp"]; 
    $datacad      = $_GET ["DataCad"]; 

    // essa linha só define a query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO respostas
        (resp_id,resp_loja,resp_usuario,resp_questionario,resp_area,resp_subgrupo,resp_pergunta_id,resp_resposta,resp_data,resp_status)
        VALUES
        ('','$loja','$id_usuario','$questionario','$area','1','$idpergunta','$resp','$datacad','1')";

    // essa linha que executa
    mysql_query($sql, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Mas para isso funcionar, você deve alterar seu botão para:

```
<button id='button' type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Responder</button>
```

Dessa forma, só vai inserir quando você apertar no botão, pois o `name="submit"` vai fazer o `GET["submit"]` existir e entrar no `if`.

Comment: Ele passa tudo certinho na query_string,mais ainda não ta inserindo nada.

Comment: Oi Berriel,deu certo,mais o ponto chave foi o button,que você indicou,Obrigado,segue resultado na resposta.

Comment: @Otacio se minha resposta foi útil, por favor, marque como resposta ou dê um voto, obrigado

Comment: Ok,mais uma vez obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido:

```
 include("conexao.php");
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    $loja         = $_GET ["loja"];
    $id_usuario  = $_GET ["id_usuario"]; 
    $questionario = $_GET ["questionario"];
    $area         = $_GET ["area"];
    $idpergunta   = $_GET ["pergunta"];   
    $resp         = $_GET ["resp"]; 
    $datacad      = $_GET ["data_cad"]; 

  $sql_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO respostas 
  (resp_id,resp_loja,resp_usuario,resp_questionario,resp_area,resp_subgrupo,resp_pergunta_id,resp_resposta,resp_data,resp_status)
  VALUES 
  ('','$loja','$id_usuario','$questionario','$area','1','$idpergunta','$resp','$datacad','1')") 
   or die (mysql_error());
   @mysql_query($sql_insert,$conexao); }
```

Deu certo após fazer as seguintes alterações indicadas por nosso colega @Berriel em sua resposta.

Comment: Não use @ no seu código

Comment: ok,esse @ peguei em um insert na internet,qual a lógica dele?

Comment: [Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/91)

Comment: E as funções mysql já foram removidas das versões mais novas do PHP.

Comment: Ok,Obrigado pela informação.