# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Tags: php, mysql

Estou montando um conexão com o banco de dados, porem me retorna este erro:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp64\www\login\conexao.php on line 2

Código:

```
<?php
@connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Erro na conexão");
mysql_select_db("tcc")or die ("Base não encontrada")
?>
```

Alguma idéia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As variáveis do PHP devem ser prefixadas com **`$`** e não com **`@`**. Apenas mude o código para:

```
<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Erro na conexão");
    mysql_select_db("tcc") or die ("Base não encontrada")
?>
```

O **@** serve para suprimir erros, se essa era a sua intenção, dê uma lida em [Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84178/por-que-dizem-que-utilizar-arroba-pra-suprimir-erros-%C3%A9-uma-m%C3%A1-pr%C3%A1tica)

---

#### Observação:

Como já foi dito muitas vezes aqui no site, não é aconselhável usar as funções `mysql`, elas estão obsoletas, `mysqli` serve para substituí-las.

Veja mais em [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%c3%a3o-devemos-usar-fun%c3%a7%c3%b5es-do-tipo-mysql/4675?s=1|0.0000#4675)