# Chat não aparece

Tags: php, html

Boa noite pessoal, e ai tudo bom com vocês ?

Galera eu criei um código bem simples,

SE estiver ativado exiba o chat , se estiver desativado exiba a mensagem de erro, se o chat estiver ativado ele deve exibir o chat, porém, ele exibi a variável e não o código que é para ser mostrado

```
define("Chat_Enable", false); // -- Ativar/Destivar Chat do Servidor
define("Chat_Scripts", '<embed  src="http://www.xatech.com/web_gear/chat/chat.swf" quality= "high" width= "500" height= "300" name= "chat" FlashVars="id=158331371&rl=Brazilian" align="middle" allowscriptaccess= "sameDomain" type= "application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage= "http://xat.com/update_flash.shtml" /></embed>'); // -- Script do Chat
```

Código para exibir o chat

```
<?php
       if(@Chat_Enable == false)
       {
         echo "<div class=\"info-box\"> O Chat se encontra Desativado</div>";
       }
       else
       {

      echo @Chat_Scripts;

       }
       ?>
```

Ao invés de exibir o chat, ele exibe o nome da variável ou seja "Chat_Scripts", podem me informar onde está o erro no código ?

Comment: Pergunta: por quê o uso do `@` na frente das constantes? Os códigos estão no mesmo arquivo?

Comment: para esconder o erro , estão em arquivos separados, porém inclusos

Comment: Já que está dando errado, não seria interessante o ver o erro que está dando? Dica pessoal: evite ao máximo (mesmo) usar o @, pois uma aplicação sai do controle muito fácil nesses casos.

Answer (score 1):

Isso irá ocorrer porque não está incluindo o outro arquivo e justamente por está escondendo a mensagem de erro dificulta saber o motivo do problema. Evite utilizar o `@`, na verdade *nunca* utilize, muito menos se está num fase de desenvolvimento, afinal se está desenvolvendo alguma coisa qual o motivo de esconder a mensagem de erro, que estão ali para lhe ajudar?! Recomendo que leia [publicação sobre este assunto.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84178/por-que-dizem-que-utilizar-arroba-pra-suprimir-erros-%C3%A9-uma-m%C3%A1-pr%C3%A1tica)

---

Quando você faz:

```
@Chat_Scripts;
```

Você remove o `Notice: Use of undefined constant Chat_Scripts - assumed 'Chat_Scripts' in /in/meLso on line 3'`, isso ocorre duas vezes. Por isso ele dá um `echo` de `Chat_Scripts`, porque assume que seria `echo 'Chat_Scripts'`.

Remover a mensagem de erro não corrige o erro, colocar o  `@` não é a solução. O que ocorre é que constante não pode ser acessada, como dito na mensagem, para resolver você deve utilizar `include()` entre os arquivos ou colocar todas as informações num só arquivo, assim basta juntar as duas partes de código que tem em um só.

Por exemplo:

```
C:.
├───inc
│       chat.php
│
└───public_html
        index.php
```

Existem duas pastas, na hierarquia mostrada acima, cada pasta com um arquivo diferente.

O `C:/servidor/inc/` `chat.php` irá possuir:

```
const CHAT_ENABLE = 1;
const CHAT_HTML = [
    1 => '<embed  src="http://www.xatech.com/web_gear/chat/chat.swf" quality= "high" width= "500" height= "300" name= "chat" FlashVars="id=158331371&rl=Brazilian" align="middle" allowscriptaccess= "sameDomain" type= "application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage= "http://xat.com/update_flash.shtml" /></embed>',
    0 => '<div class="info-box"> O Chat se encontra Desativado</div>'
    ];
```

O `C:/servidor/public_html/` `index.php` possui:

```
include('../inc/chat');

echo CHAT_HTML[ CHAT_ENABLE ];
```

O `include` irá incluir o arquivo `chat.php`, assim irá existir o `CHAT_HTML` e também o `CHAT_ENABLE` que foram definidos.

---

*As modificações que fiz são opcionais, o que você realmente precisa fazer é incluir um arquivo no outro, utilizando `include`.*

---

Se não quiser o `include()` (ou similar) apenas utilize então:

```
define("Chat_Enable", false); // -- Ativar/Destivar Chat do Servidor
define("Chat_Scripts", '<embed  src="http://www.xatech.com/web_gear/chat/chat.swf" quality= "high" width= "500" height= "300" name= "chat" FlashVars="id=158331371&rl=Brazilian" align="middle" allowscriptaccess= "sameDomain" type= "application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage= "http://xat.com/update_flash.shtml" /></embed>'); // -- Script do Chat


if(!Chat_Enable){

    echo "<div class=\"info-box\"> O Chat se encontra Desativado</div>";

}else{

    echo Chat_Scripts;

}
```

Isso irá resolver o problema porque o `Chat_Enable` e o `Chat_Scripts` estão definidos, [teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e05c389f9d0f5deec102f6e76f72a75c993f75e)