# Erro 404 em um arquivo php

Tags: php, xampp

Estou tentando fazer um formulário, criado no arquivo index.php, que envia por método `POST` para a página cadastro.php e com um `header()` mando uma variável de verificação de volta para o *index*.

Porém, quando ele volta para a página index.php, diz que o arquivo não foi encontrado e dá `Error 404`.

**index.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Exercicio 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    echo '<form action="cadastro.php" method="post">
            Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" value="" /> <br />
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="" /> <br />
            Senha: <input type="password" name="senha" value="" /> <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </form>';

    if(@$_GET['login'] == 1){
        echo 'Informe nome novamente!';
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**cadastro.php**:

```
<?php
require 'connection.php';
require 'database.php';

$usuario = array(
    'nome' => $_POST['nome'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'senha' => $_POST['senha'],
    );

if(empty($_POST['nome']) || strlen($_POST['nome']) < 5){
    header("Location:index.php login=1");
}
else if(!strstr($_POST['email'], '@') || strlen($_POST['email']) < 5){
    header("Location:index.php login=2");
}
else if(empty($_POST['senha']) || strlen($_POST['senha']) < 5){
    header("Location:index.php login=3");
}
else{
    DBCreate('usuarios', $usuario);
    header("Location:index.php login=4");
}  ?>
```

Estou usando o XAMPP no Windows.

Comment: O seu `header` não deveria ser `Location: index.php?login=X`, onde `X` é o respectivo valor? Aliás, ele diz que qual arquivo não existe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os enderenços estão incorretos:

```
header("Location:index.php login=1");
...
header("Location:index.php login=2");
...
header("Location:index.php login=3");
...
header("Location:index.php login=4");
```

Troque por:

```
header("Location:index.php?login=1");
...
header("Location:index.php?login=2");
...
header("Location:index.php?login=3");
...
header("Location:index.php?login=4");
```

Vale lembrar que o `Location` é um header da **resposta** do HTTP, ou seja não é o PHP que redireciona e sim o navegador ao receber os headers, então o `location:` deve conter um caminho **relativo** ou **absoluto** ao endereço atual da página.

### Sobre o uso do arroba:

Notei que esta usando `@` para suprimir os "warnings", no caso seria legal dar uma lida nisto:

- [Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/3635)

Comment: Aaah, muito obrigado, fiquei horas lendo e nao havia visto que faltava o "?".

Comment: Estava dando um warning na index, pois dizia que a variavel login ainda nao havia sido instanciada, mas como nao precisava da variavel a primeira vez que abro o index, resolvi suprimir aquele warning.